# How do I fix a tuple in list error

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I have this bit of code:

```
Points = [ [400,100],[600,100],[800,100] , [300,300],[400,300],[500,300],[600,300] ,         [200,500],[400,500],[600,500],[800,500],[1000,500] , [300,700],[500,700][700,700][900,700] , [200,900],[400,900],[600,900] ]
```

And it produces this Error:

```
  line 43, in <module>
    Points = [ [400,100],[600,100],[800,100] , [300,300],[400,300],[500,300],[600,300] , [200,500],[400,500],[600,500],[800,500],[1000,500] , [300,700],[500,700][700,700][900,700] , [200,900],[400,900],[600,900] ]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot two commas:

```
[500,700][700,700][900,700]
```

Now Python sees an attempt to index the list on the left-hand side with a `(700, 700)` tuple:

```
>>> [500,700][700,700]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

The second `[900, 700]` 'list' would give you the same problem but doesn't yet come into play.

Fix it by adding commas between:

```
[500, 700], [700, 700], [900, 700]
```

or, as a complete list:

```
 Points = [[400, 100], [600, 100], [800, 100], [300, 300], [400, 300], [500, 300], [600, 300], [200, 500], [400, 500], [600, 500], [800, 500], [1000, 500], [300, 700], [500, 700], [700, 700], [900, 700], [200, 900], [400, 900], [600, 900]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to seperate a few by commas. See the fix.

```
>>> Points = [[400,100], [600,100], [800,100], [300,300], [400,300], [500,300], [600,300] ,[200,500], [400,500], [600,500], [800,500], [1000,500], [300,700], [500,700], [700,700],[900,700], [200,900], [400,900], [600,900]]
```

Forgetting the commas leads Python to believe that you're trying to access the first list with the second, which throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate each of the lists (in the outer list) with a `,`:

```
Points = [ [400,100],[600,100],[800,100] , [300,300],[400,300],[500,300],[600,300] ,[200,500],[400,500],[600,500],[800,500],[1000,500] , [300,700],[500,700],[700,700],[900,700] , [200,900],[400,900],[600,900] ]
```